# flutter webview keyboard cannot show up

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I tried to integrate the webview, in the flutter app. After adding the code in the example, the page loads normally, but when I click on the input box in the page, no soft keyboard pops up,

Answer (score 8):

This problem only happens on Android and it is a known issue here. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19718.

If your app does not need the webview to be on the same screen with other Flutter widgets, I recommend this webview library from the Flutter community. There is no keyboard issue here. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late but changing the webview version to v3.0.0 actually solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried multiple things but finally i have fixed it through scaffold, now my keyboard is opening.

just wrap your WebView inside Scaffold widget and apply following property inside scaffold.

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to the initState() resolved the issue for me.

I had this issue on Android devices alone

```
void initState() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: That fixed the issue for me on Android 13, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one can use for now. Hope flutter team fix it soon.

You need to open your android project in Android Studio to view all dependencies and in the `webview_flutter`

To fix most recent version of code, besides import

```
import android.app.Activity;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
```

Change:

```
webView = new InputAwareWebView(context, containerView);
```

To:

```
Context activityContext = context;
Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
if (appContext instanceof FlutterApplication) {
  Activity currentActivity = ((FlutterApplication) appContext).getCurrentActivity();
  if (currentActivity != null) {
    activityContext = currentActivity;
  }
}
webView = new InputAwareWebView(activityContext, containerView);
```

Original answer here: @ryanhz https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25767#issuecomment-588603862