# Flutter InAppWebView doesn't open keyboard

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using flutter [InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

problem is in my web view there is textfields to fill by user. but when the text box tapped the keyboard doesn't open. I don't want to use `webview_flutter` I want to use `flutter_inappwebview`

Webview is loading there is no issue. I want to open keyboard when user enter the values.

```
InAppWebView(
       key: _key,
       gestureRecognizers: _gestureRecognizers,
       initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse(
               url,
             ),
           ),
          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
             _controller = controller;
          },
          onProgressChanged:
             (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
              setState(() {
                  _progress = progress / 100;
              });
           },
          },
      ),
```

Comment: Try with this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805743/flutter-webview-keyboard-cannot-show-up

Comment: problem is in InAppWebView. not the Webview. these are two different packages